# How can i convert an HTML template to aspx dot net files easily?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, xhtml

does any body know any perfect tutorial, that i want to convert my XHTML CSS based template to aspx pages with code behinds.

I tried myself, and i get successful to some extent, but not properly. I want to convert all files to aspx pages with CODE BEHIND CS FILES , its very important. Also how to make html header footers to master pages.

Thanks
Atif

Comment: Perfect?  That's a tall order my friend...

Comment: Abe, do you know any solution

Comment: Unfortunately, I think Frank's solution is going to be your best bet.  If you want to use masterpages, then this gets much more complex

Answer (score 3):

Copy the html head and body into a newly created aspx page in Visual Studio

Comment: Probably not the answer you wanted but, this is most likely your best bet.

Comment: Yep. No way but manual. Also, don't forget you can use masterpages

Comment: Create a Master Page file and add the recurring template html and header to that file.

Add a reference to the master page in the first line of each aspx page.

http://odetocode.com/code/450.aspx